# Show that cardinality of a set is an equivalent relation - Equivalent according to Zermelo

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

This question is long but the basic idea is super simple: show that $|A| = |B|, |B| = |C| \Rightarrow |A| = |C|$. So please don't be intimidated by the length of this post.

First some definition:

A set $W$ is a connection of two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ (according to Zermelo) if the following hold:

1. $Z \in W \Rightarrow (\exists x \in A, y \in B)[Z = \{x, y\}]$
2. For each $x \in A$, there is exactly one $y \in B$ such that $\{x, y \} \in W$
3. For each $y \in B$, there is exactly one $x \in A$ such that $\{x, y \} \in W$

For the sake of clarity, we will refer to each element (which is itself a set) as a "pair set" whenever needed; this is done to emphasize that  the connection $\Sigma(A,B)$ is not the elements of the form $\{x,y\}$ satisfying condition 2 and 3 above, but the SET of all such elements.

In other words, $\Sigma(A,B)$ refers to an entire set of "pair sets" $\{x,y\}$ satisfying conditions 2 and 3. For example, $\Sigma(\{a,b,c\}, \{a,d\}) = \emptyset$ while $\Sigma(\mathbb N, \{1,2,3,...\})$ could be either the set of all "pair sets" of the form $\{n, n+1\}$ or the set of all "pair sets" $\{0,4\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 2\}, \{3,1\}, \{n, n+1\}$ with $n \geq 4$ (as an aside, notice also that $\{1,3\}$ and $\{3,1\}$ are actually the same element). Of course, $\Sigma(\mathbb N, \{1,2,3,...\})$ could be neither of the two. Hence there can be multiple options for $\Sigma(A, B)$ if $A$ and $B$ have same cardinality.

We may assume that for any two disjoint sets $A, B$, there always exists a connection of the two, denoted $\Sigma(A,B)$.

Intuitively, $\Sigma(A,B)$ is nonempty if and only if they have same cardinality.

Now I wish to prove the last part of $x3.3$:

[image]

Thanks for all the comments. I believe that the book has a typo and it should read "...and nonempty connections" exist (see also the last sentence of next paragraph).

It's also worth mentioning that $\Sigma(A,B)$ is not a function of $A,B$ (example provided earlier with $\mathbb N$ and $\{1,2,3,...\}$); in other words, we are not sure what exactly it is referring to, although we only know the property of its elements (as an analogy, we know what "a set of $5$ real numbers, each of which is greater than $2816$" is referring to, but there are several types of such a set - it could be $\{10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005\}$ or $\{ \pi^{100}, 19378, 10001, 48888, 2817\}$). Hence, the equivalence relation actually should be interpreted as "$...\exists \Sigma(A,C) \neq \emptyset, \exists \Sigma(B,C) \neq \emptyset$."

The only thing I am having difficulty is the last of the equivalent condition, transitivity. Here it is difficulty since, though the result is intuitively clear, I am not allowed to create bijection between sets and am only allowed to use the existence of class and first six of $ZF$ Axioms, namely axiom of extensionality, emptyset and pairset axioms, separation axiom, powerset axiom, unionset axiom, and axiom of infinity.

Say $D$ and $E$ are appropriate sets "connecting" the pairs $A,B$ and $B,C$, respectively. If $D=E$ then of course we are done, but I am lost on what to do if that is not the case.

Comment: I think you should say $\Sigma(A, B)$ exists iff they have the same cardinality. Because when they don't have the same cardinality, $\Sigma(A, B)$ can't even exist, let alone being none-empty.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: Why would you say that? It's a set of "connections". If there are none, it's empty. How would it "not exist"?

Comment: This is really just composing functions, but here functions are represented in a different and peculiar way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Oh yeah, i misread that, i thought $\Sigma(A, B)$ was just one of those connections.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, But then again he says "We may assume that for any two disjoint sets A,B, there always exists a connection of the two, denoted ∑(A,B).". So he means that $\Sigma(A, B)$ is just a connection not the set of all connections.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri: If you read through that, and in the screen shot, you'd find the line you refer to is a typo.

Comment: In particular you have no axiom of Regularity? That does make it more difficult...

Comment: Have you proved $X\sim_{\rm Z} X$? If you apply that to $X=A\cup B\cup C$, then take the set that connects $X$ to itself, and consider only those elements of it that correspond to elements of $A$...

Comment: By the way, $\Sigma(A,B)$ is certainly a function of $A$ and $B$, in the sense that if you have $A$ and $B$, then there is one unique set that the notation $\Sigma(A,B)$ stands for. $\Sigma(A,B)$ would be the _set of all connections_, not itself a connection. Your example with $\Sigma(\mathbb N_0,\mathbb N_+)$ does not contradict this because (even if you were using ordered pairs) what you quote would be two different _connections_, which are _elements_ of $\Sigma(\mathbb N_0,\mathbb N_+)$, not two candidates for being $\Sigma(\mathbb N_0,\mathbb N_+)$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty here is to find some way to construct a set that is "obviously" in bijective correspondence with $A$ and yet disjoint from both $A$ and $C$.

The same difficulty arises if you want to show that $A\sim_{\rm Z} A$.

Without "cheating" and defining Kuratowski pairs so we can just proceed in a more modern way, and also without Regularity, the best I can think of is to *diagonalize* our way to some new elements. The core of that would be the following lemma -- I'll leave it to you to apply it in your particular situation...

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a set. There exists a $Y$ disjoint from $X$ such that $\Sigma(X,Y)$ is nonempty.

**Proof.** Choose and fix two sets $0$ and $1$ that are not elements of $X$. (That has to be possible, or Separation would create a contradiction through Russell's paradox). Then define
$$ \overline X = \{ \{0,x\} \mid x\in X\land \{0,x\}\notin x \} $$
and then set
$$ Y = \{ \overline X \cup \{ \{1,x\} \} \mid x\in X \} $$

Even though it looks like we need Replacement, these in fact both exist due to Separation because they are both are subsets of $\mathcal P(X\cup\{0,1\})$.

But no $y\in Y$ can equal any $x\in X$, because $\{0,x\}\in y$ iff $\{0,x\}\in \overline X$ which is exactly if $\{0,x\}\notin x$.

Comment: @BlueRoses: Russells paradox shows that there is no set of all sets. In particular $X$ cannot be a set of all sets, so there is some $0\notin X$. But $X\cup\{0\}$ is not a set of all sets either, so we can pick a $1$ not in _that_.

Comment: Or, by unfolding the argument of Russell's paradox, you can concretely set $0=\{x\in X\mid x\notin x\}$ and set $1=0\cup\{0\}$, (since $0$ cannot contain itself because $0\subseteq X$ and $0\notin X$).

Comment: @BlueRoses: Why would they have a different number of elements? _By definition_ $Y$ has one element arising from each $x\in X$, namely the set $\overline X\cup\{\{1,x\}\}$. (And these are all different because each of them has only that one element containing $1$).

Comment: @BlueRoses: Mostly by having plenty of experience and knowing a lot of tricks already. In this case, _diagonalization_ is a standard trick for constructing something of a given kind that differs from a lot of other things at the same time -- or in other words, to find something _outside_ a given set. So that was the "bigger gun" I pulled out when about 10 minutes of trying to make something simpler work didn't yield results. The rest was just a matter of puzzling out how the details would fit together.

Comment: Henning, Russell's Paradox shows that there is no set of all sets which are not members of themselves, which in turn implies that not every class is a set. In presence of full Separation this implies there is no set of all sets as well. But New Foundations avoids Russell's Paradox while retaining a universal set just fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: All that is true of course -- but the OP specified explicitly that he's working in a subset of ZF that includes Separation. What he's trying to prove is no true in NF at all -- in particular the $A\sim_{\rm Z} A$ part would not hold when $A=V$.